# Laravel: Skip time slots from Carbon\CarbonPeriod some time ranges

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm developing a booking system for a various packages having different durations for each. The customer should get available time slots from a selected date. The date may contain different package bookings with different time intervals. So, What I'm trying to do is to extract available time slots on the date by skipping all booked time slots.

Expected output is:

```
08:00 AM
10:30 AM // 09:00 AM has a booking. and its duration is 1.5 hours
11:30 AM // The current package has 1 hour duration

... until the shop closes for eg 08:00 PM
```

I'm using CarbonPeriod to get list of time slots. But, I can't apply the filters to skip all booked time slots.

```
$hours = new CarbonPeriod(
    $opening,
    $this->duration() . ' minutes',
    $closing->subMinutes($this->duration())
);

$hours->filter(function ($date) use ($booked) {
    $toSkip = [];
    foreach ($booked as $bookedItem) {
        $bookingTime = Carbon::parse($bookedItem->time);
        $completingTime = Carbon::parse($bookedItem->time)->addMinutes($bookedItem->package->duration());

        if ($date->isBetween($bookingTime, $completingTime)) {
            array_push($toSkip, $date);
        }
    }
    return !in_array($date, $toSkip);
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'd imagine one of your issues is that your `return` statement is inside your `foreach` loop. This means that it filter method will only check the first item in `$booked`

Comment: @Rwd, Thank you for your support! Here is what I get after I put return statement outside the loop:
`[
     "11:00 AM",
     "02:00 PM",
     "03:00 PM",
     "04:00 PM",
     "05:00 PM",
     "06:00 PM",
     "07:00 PM",
   ]
`
But, there a missing slot between 10:30 AM - 11:00 AM, 01:30 PM - 02:30 PM. Can I acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, this sounds like a job for [spatie/opening-hours](https://github.com/spatie/opening-hours) or the version dedicated to Carbon: [cmixin/business-time](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time)

Definition looks like:

```php
BusinessTime::enable(Carbon::class, [
  'monday' => ['09:00-12:00', '13:00-18:00'],
  'tuesday' => ['09:00-12:00', '13:00-18:00'],
  'wednesday' => ['09:00-12:00'],
  'thursday' => ['09:00-12:00', '13:00-18:00'],
  'friday' => ['09:00-12:00', '13:00-20:00'],
  'saturday' => ['09:00-12:00', '13:00-16:00'],
]);
```

Then with `CarbonPeriod`, use the custom step:

```php
$period = CarbonPeriod::create(
    $opening,
    static fn ($date) => $date->nextOpen(),
    $closing,
);

foreach ($period as $slot) {
  echo "$slot\n";
}
```

You also can easily convert AM/PM string to h0-23 format with:

```php
Carbon::parse('11:20 PM')->format('H:i')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, this didn't meet my requirement. I've to display a list of available time slots to the customer. This package is very help ful to check whether the selected time is available or not.

Comment: Once you have the range, you should just loop over using `->nextOpen()` sure thing is you should not iterate over each minute, it will be extremely slow.